# windows nodejs child_process exec echo always print childProcess instance

Tags: node.js, windows, echo, child-process

like this:

[image: Screenshot]

I has try with cmd.exe, powershell.exe, git-bash.exe, both of them have this behavior. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If evaluated REPL input is an expression, evaluated result is printed in console, otherwise `undefined` is printed.

As [the reference](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) states, `childprocess_exec()` returns [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess) object:

> Returns: `<ChildProcess>`